# Add tags in data base (split many to many relation-ship Sql )

Tags: sql

I need to add a tags for 3 tables in my relational data base ! So adding tags as a table is not the best solution, because I'll be obliged to create 3 tables for the 3 different tables existant
What is the optimised solution that I can use ?

Comment: Does the tag list need to be different based on table?

Comment: Please edit the question, and show an example of what you are talking about.  Not very clear.  Thanks

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: I have 3 tables purpose, training and session (in a company) I need to add tags for these tables. I found a solution whitch is to add a table tag. But adding 3 tables in my data base it's a lot, I think that this is not the good idea. So I'm searching about another solution

Answer (score 0):

Just use those tags in One Main Tag Table and make those tags as foreign keys to your existing three tables primary keys like

```
     CREATE TABLE Main_Tag
   (ID_table1 varchar(10),
    ID_table2 varchar(10),
   ID_table3 varchar(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_table1) references
  Table1(Id_tab1),
 FOREIGN KEY (ID_table2) references
  Table2(Id_table2),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_table3) references
  Table3(Id_tab3));
```